# Set TTL when using Aerospike with Spark in Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, aerospike, ttl

I’m new to Aerospike. We are using Aerospike with Spark (Java) for our system.

I want to set TTL for a dataframe everytime the data is written to Aerospike. However, I could not find a way to do that even from document or Internet.

My current write syntax:

```
networkDs.write()
        .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
        .format("com.aerospike.spark.sql")
        .option("aerospike.set", Const.AEROSPIKE_SET)
        .option("aerospike.updateByKey", "id")
        .save();
```

Can somebody tell me how to do that?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understand your question well but to use TTL while saving with `aerospike`, you should store it in a column in the `DataSet`/`DataFrame` before it's saved.

**Note:** **Time to live** (TTL) can be set individually on each record.

To enable updates to TTL, and additional option is specified:

```
option("aerospike.ttlColumn", "expiry")
```

This means that the TTL is your column `expiry`.

I hope this helps.

For further information, I advice you to look at the `aerospike` [tutorial documentation](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/connectors/spark/tutorial_2.html).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Actually the current schema already has default columns for TTL as I print it out (__ttl). Should I still include the above option line to the write operation? Furthermore, there's no param for me to specify the exact TTL, like 300 or 500?

Comment: Yes @tuancoltech . You'll need to specify the column, I'm not sure if there is a default setting for that.

Comment: I just tested by adding an expiry field in my object, and it works. However, by this way we'll always have to create an additional field in our original data object which in my humble opinion, is a little bit redundant, since I thought Aerospike had its own mechanism to manage the expiration time of a row regardless of what information an object contains. What do you think about it, @eliasah?

Comment: @tuancoltech That connector is maintained by `aerospike`. I also agree with you about redundancy but this is the way that they've implemented it. There is no other way for now. I have shared with you the official documentation tutorial and that's how they do it.

Comment: Sure. Thanks a lot Eliasah.